# Infer signature of multiple generic functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm having trouble matching the function signature of multiple generic functions. I'm trying to create two **factory** functions, which return **async** and **sync** results. However, typescript is giving me an implementation error. I'm not understanding the reason for the error, especially since using the code seems to be okay.

implementation:

```
class Item {
  constructor(public data: { id: string; name: string }) {}
}

type Factory<T extends any[], M> = (...args: T) => M
type AsyncFactory<T extends any[], M> = (...args: T) => Promise<M>

type FactoryHandler<T extends any[], M> = Factory<T, M> | AsyncFactory<T, M>

class Collection<
  A extends any[],
  M extends Item,
  FF extends FactoryHandler<A, M>
> {
  constructor(public factory: FF) {}

  createItem(...args: A): ReturnType<FF> extends Promise<M> ? Promise<M> : M {
    return this.factory(...args) // error
    /*
    Type 'M | Promise<M>' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<FF> extends Promise<M> ? Promise<M> : M'.
    Type 'M' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<FF> extends Promise<M> ? Promise<M> : M'.
    Type 'Item' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<FF> extends Promise<M> ? Promise<M> : M'.ts(2322)
    */
  }
}
```

Using both `async` and `sync` functions is inferred correctly.

```
const createItemFactory = function (data: { id: string; name: string }) {
  return new Item(data)
}

const asyncCreateItemFactory = function (data: { id: string; name: string }) {
  return Promise.resolve(new Item(data))
}

const collA = new Collection(createItemFactory)
const item = collA.createItem({ id: 'a', name: 'b' }) // item

const collB = new Collection(asyncCreateItemFactory)
collB.createItem({ id: 'a', name: 'b' }).then((item) => console.log(item)) // async OK
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-7Q-05JHoxBY-H5sb8Mm-enhZnTBLzFKVnC8yXoCqh5roNry5W-aya+H6-cm2AE6322Y04Kuz7BtnpYOi8GC2PtpOYvAILQAEwAZkvl80bo9dqB+jpWAd0HIEDAkjMtfwADW2A4iQeCMsyrLFAiOwkuQhTwO8hDRNwvACGgQgiNAYiqLI8iKMo4hSBoNJAgaXZyIgADucBIGyKFgA+WBviBUaQGcDzgUgkHkkYMFwW8RDITw-CCMIBE4XIChKFhKhEVoupQmRRpDjEjIQM8ABuiC0IQVE0SgtD0ZojHMUQoEEC8PxRLp1FPC8iACYQtAMkyXG0VBNiMSxQi0TsFkgDkMQuRBtG0OhYmpmAvpBHh0m+kwobyR+rC0Tc3n+QAQjsNnQHZrwIUQtBsYUHGuSy7k8V5zwgBlQWceVBnhZhvpRTFUkCPFiWaGeJqrLQtApSgaThCBzyIDEID4JIA20cZ7qOsVHAAPIANLYEAA)

Comment: Using a conditional in a return type is always rough.  You might have to assert it. `return this.factory(...args) as ReturnType<FF>`

Comment: Alternatively, you can always return a `Promise` regardless of whether the factory function is `async`. `async createItem(...args: A): Promise<M> {  return this.factory(...args); }`

Comment: `as ReturnType<FF>` doesn't help. As for the second case `: Promise<M>`  that infers that all `create` function variations return a promise.

Comment: For the first case you wouldn't need the conditional in the return.  Just do `createItem(...args: A): ReturnType<FF> { return this.factory(...args) as ReturnType<FF>; }`.  For the second, we are causing non-async functions to return a `Promise` by making the method async.  I don't think it's what you want but I kind of like it because it's a level of abstraction that allows you to treat all `Collection` objects the same way regardless of whether their factory is async or not.  So it would change how you are using the non-async collections because you would have to treat them as async.

Comment: Oh, I see, I've removed the conditional return, and that will have to do for now. I  want the user to explicitly know if the `create` function returns a promise. There will be cases where the synchronous return is preferred. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript sees the returned value as the union of two possibilities `M | Promise<M>`.  This union is not assignable to your conditional.  Typescript is not smart enough to understand which situations return `M` and which return `Promise<M>`.

#### With `as` Assertion

As easy fix is to use an `as` assertion to tell Typescript that the return type of `createItem` matches the return type of `this.factory` which is type `FF`.

```
createItem(...args: A): ReturnType<FF> {
  return this.factory(...args) as ReturnType<FF>; 
}
```

#### Without Assertion

We can get a proper return type without assertion, but it requires tweaking the `Collection` class.  We can use the generic `M` to describe the item exactly as it is returned from the factory -- as either `Item | Promise<Item>`.  Basically we are handling the synchronous/asynchronous distinction in `M` rather than in `FF`.  Now all factories are simply functions `(...args: A) => M` because `M` itself might be a `Promise`.

```
class Collection<
  A extends any[],
  M extends Item | Promise<Item>
> {
  constructor(public factory: (...args: A) => M) {}

  createItem(...args: A): M {
    return this.factory(...args); 
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mq85RN)

Comment: "Without assertion" is a very clean solution. I can't change the `M` generic right now so  I've created another one `R extends M | Promise<M>` and I'm using that one for the return type.

Comment: Which solution would you go with?

Comment: I would go with "Without assertion".  It's generally better to have less generic variables (which now makes me want to go back and write it with just `FF`!).  I included both because I figured that there might be other methods in the class which would need to have their types modified so the assertion is easier to implement.